# Jquery: Get the functions from a php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm new to jquery and php both. I have an html page and need to use some functions in a php file via jquery, and then print the results in html.

What I'm trying to do is counting the number of files in 3 different directories, and then print their results in 3 different divs. When I write only one function in the php file, and call it via `load` in jquery, it works fine. But I don't know how to use this method for 3 different functions in the same php file. Could you please help me?

HTML:

```
<div class="result1"></div>
<div class="result2"></div>
<div class="result3"></div>
<script>window.onload = stats()</script>
```

JS:

```
function stats() {
$('.result1').load("counter.php"); //I don't know what to add here to get the result of only the function a1 in counter.php
$('.result2').load("counter.php"); //and for a2
$('.result3').load("counter.php"); //and for a3
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

function a1() {
$i = 0;
$dir = '../folder1/';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) $i++;}}
echo "$i";
}

function a2() {
$i = 0;
$dir = '../folder2/';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) $i++;}}
echo "$i";
}

function a3() {
$i = 0;
$dir = '../folder3/';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) $i++;}}
echo "$i";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a URL parameter that indicates which function to call. Then check that in the PHP.

JS:

```
function stats() {
    $('.result1').load("counter.php?action=a1");
    $('.result2').load("counter.php?action=a2");
    $('.result3').load("counter.php?action=a3");
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

switch ($_GET['action']) {
case 'a1':
    a1();
    break;
case 'a2':
    a2();
    break;
case 'a3':
    a3();
    break;
}

function a1() {
    $i = 0;
    $dir = '../folder1/';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) $i++;}}
    echo "$i";
}

function a2() {
    $i = 0;
    $dir = '../folder2/';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) $i++;}}
    echo "$i";
}

function a3() {
    $i = 0;
    $dir = '../folder3/';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) $i++;}}
    echo "$i";
}

?>
```